# Align columns with numbers by decimal point and ratio symbol (colon :)

Tags: tables, tabularx, columns, makecell, decimal-number

I want to achieve alignment by decimal number AND the colon (:) ratio symbol, similar to what is shown in the code below as opposed to what is shown in the figure. I would welcome any suggestions for general table aesthetics also. Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[abbreviations=true,per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!t]
\caption{Focus as a Ratio of the Total}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ >{\bfseries}c S[table-format=2.2] }
\toprule
\thead{ID} & {\thead{Ratio\\ {[Focus : Total]} }} \\
\midrule
1    &{1 :  18.7}\\
2    &{1 :   0.2}\\
3    &{1 : 105.6}\\
4    &{1 :  58.7}\\
5    &{1 :   0  }\\
6    &{1 :   1.5}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: ratio image]

Comment: If the ratio was defined "the other way around" (18.7 : 1 instead of 1 : 18.7) you could use something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208755/134144

Comment: cant the focus column be removed -- it is common value 1 -- that will leave only the total value which can be easily expressed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With minimal visual formatting:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[abbreviations=true,per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\caption{Focus as a Ratio of the Total}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
  >{\bfseries}c
  >{\enspace}c
  @{${}:{}$\hspace{-\tabcolsep}}
  S[table-format=3.1]
}
\toprule
\thead{ID} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Ratio \\\relax [Focus${}:{}$Total]}} \\
\midrule
1 & 1 &  18.7 \\
2 & 1 &   0.2 \\
3 & 1 & 105.6 \\
4 & 1 &  58.7 \\
5 & 1 &   0   \\
6 & 1 &   1.5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @egreg, that works really well

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possibility with three columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[abbreviations=true,per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!t]
\caption{Focus as a Ratio of the Total}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ >{\bfseries}c>{1}r!{$ : \!$} S[table-format=3.1, table-number-alignment=left] }
\toprule
\thead{ID} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{\thead{Ratio\\ {[Focus : Total]}}} \\
\midrule
1 & & 18.7 \\
2 & & 0.2 \\
3 & & 105.6 \\
4 & & 58.7 \\
5 & & 0 \\
6 & & 1.5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Bernard, that works really well